# Pre selecting the text in a dropdownlist

Tags: c#, .net, sql, drop-down-menu, formview

I am trying to make the dropdownlist I have already created inside of the edit page of a formview start on the value previously selected from the sql database for the current user.

So far I have the code to populate the drop down list working correctly:

```
protected void ddlSelect_Init(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["ReinstatementCS"].ConnectionString);
    SqlCommand myCommand = new SqlCommand("SELECT Prefix, Number, ClassSection, Location, StartTime, EndTime, ClassDay, Prefix + Number  + ', Section: ' + CAST(ClassSection AS VarChar) +  ', Location: ' + Location + ', Start Time: ' + StartTime + ', End Time: ' + EndTime + ', Days: ' + ClassDay + ', Credits: ' + CAST(ClassCredit AS VarChar) AS PN, Capacity, GPAReqAbove1, GPAReqBelow1, CreditReqAbove30, CreditReqBelow30, ClassCredit, IsTransfer, SLN FROM Classes");
    myCommand.Connection = con;
    SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(myCommand);
    DataTable dt = new DataTable();
    da.Fill(dt);

    DropDownList ddlSelect = FVStudentClass.FindControl("ddlSelect") as DropDownList;
    ddlSelect.DataSource = dt;
    ddlSelect.DataTextField = "PN";
    ddlSelect.DataValueField = "SLN";
    ddlSelect.DataBind();

    con.Close();
}
```

Where SLN is the unique value for each item in the dropdownlist and PN is the background information for each item in the dropdownlist. I want the item that is highlighted to be the PN that corresponds to what that specific user already has stored in the database. The problem is that when I try to have that value selected I am using:

```
protected void FVStudentClass_ModeChanging(object sender, FormViewModeEventArgs e)
{
    SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["ReinstatementCS"].ConnectionString);
    SqlCommand myCommand = new SqlCommand("SELECT Prefix + Number  + ', Section: ' + CAST(ClassSection AS VarChar) +  ', Location: ' + Location + ', Start Time: ' + StartTime + ', End Time: ' + EndTime + ', Days: ' + ClassDay + ', Credits: ' + CAST(ClassCredit AS VarChar) AS PN, SLN FROM Classes JOIN StudentClass on SLN = SCClass WHERE SCWSUID = " + Request.QueryString["ALWSUID"]);
    myCommand.Connection = con;
    SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(myCommand);
    DataTable dt = new DataTable();
    da.Fill(dt);

    DropDownList ddlSelect = FVStudentClass.FindControl("ddlSelect") as DropDownList;
    ddlSelect.DataSource = dt;

    ddlSelect.Items.FindByText(dt.Rows[0]["PN"].ToString());
    con.Close();        
}
```

and getting the error:

```
System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
```

On the line with:

```
ddlSelect.DataSource = dt;
```

Does any one know how to fix this or should I give more information? Thanks in advance!

Edits:

I followed your guys advice and now I have:

```
 protected void FVStudentClass_ModeChanging(object sender, FormViewCommandEventArgs e)
    {
        if (FVStudentClass.CurrentMode != FormViewMode.Edit)
            return;
        SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["ReinstatementCS"].ConnectionString);
        SqlCommand myCommand = new SqlCommand("SELECT Prefix + Number  + ', Section: ' + CAST(ClassSection AS VarChar) +  ', Location: ' + Location + ', Start Time: ' + StartTime + ', End Time: ' + EndTime + ', Days: ' + ClassDay + ', Credits: ' + CAST(ClassCredit AS VarChar) AS PN, SLN FROM Classes JOIN StudentClass on SLN = SCClass WHERE SCWSUID = " + Request.QueryString["ALWSUID"]);
        myCommand.Connection = con;
        SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(myCommand);
        DataTable dt = new DataTable();
        da.Fill(dt);
        DropDownList ddlSelect = new DropDownList();
        ddlSelect = FVStudentClass.FindControl("ddlSelect") as DropDownList;
        if (ddlSelect != null)
        {
            ddlSelect.DataSource = dt;
            ddlSelect.Items.FindByText(dt.Rows[0]["PN"].ToString()).Selected = true;
        }
        con.Close();
    }
```

but I'm still stuck because the dropdownlist does not start out with the saved value being selected. Do you know how to fix this? Am I using the wrong command (Should I use something besides ModeChanging)?

Comment: I think you have to create DropDownList object first with new keyword. You are not creating any object.

Comment: @Vivek Could you show me code for that? I didn't do it in the first member and it worked ok. What would be the difference to cause a problem the second time and not the first?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Notice that after solving nullreference you will also want to change:

ddlSelect.Items.FindByText(dt.Rows[0]["PN"].ToString());

into

ddlSelect.Items.FindByText(dt.Rows[0]["PN"].ToString()).Selected = true;

so that it becomes selected

Answer (score 1):

```
DropDownList ddlSelect = FVStudentClass.FindControl("ddlSelect") as DropDownList;
```

here ddlSelect can be null so you get `System.NullReferenceException`

if you use `as` operator it can return null incase of not found control named 'ddlSelect" so better to add null check like below

```
if(ddlSelect !=null)
{
   // do the bindings 

}
```

if you want to access edit template controls you need to check the current mode equal to edit or not. if it not edit you can't find edit template controls

```
if (FormView1.CurrentMode != FormViewMode.Edit)
        return;
//your code
```

Answer (score 0):

I would check the code that you use to return the drop down menu, since you're not using the constructor or new keyword.  Is it returning a null value?